# How to access this json data 'id' inside data 'Message' in the php script below?

Tags: php, arrays, json

The variable $res returning this response below

```
   {"Status":"Success","Message":{"Id":"9235948e-5469-450e-8aaf-551772da9c6a"}}
```

How do i access this id inside message?

```
$res = $leadsquared->create_lead($data);
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$res = '{"Status":"Success","Message":{"Id":"9235948e-5469-450e-8aaf-551772da9c6a"}}';
$resArr = json_decode($res, true); // true is needed to make the output array associative.
print_r($resArr['Message']['Id']);
```

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn the json string into a php array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$result = json_decode($res,true);<br/>
$id = $result['Message']['Id']
```